# Storage configuration for GPU servers (ML training)

Tags: raid, storage

We have recently purchased a couple of high performance GPU servers to use in training AI/ML models and the job of set up and administration has fallen upon me.

I'll preface this by saying I am definitely not a sysadmin. I am an academic, so the less time I can spend on setting up and maintaining the servers the better from my PoV. They will be running Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS.

I am interested in opinions as to the storage set up for these servers. They currently have:

2x Intel S4510 480GB SATA 3 drives set up as RAID  1 via a hardware RAID controller (a BROADCOM 9560-8i).
2x Samsung PM983 960GB NVMe drives.

I'm not particularly concerned about data recovery as all data will be backed up on other systems (as mandated by our university's data management policy for research data). I'm more concerned with speed of loading and processing data.

My current plan is to use the hardware RAID 1 array for the system partition and then software RAID0 on the NVMe drives as a user partition (so resulting in about 2TB of data storage).

My question is: is this a ridiculous idea or does it sound reasonable?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly putting the OS/applications on the R1 (2 x 480GB) makes sense.

Obviously you've not mentioned your actual storage needs for the data, clearly you don't need oceans of storage and as you say you're not too worried about the actual data itself.

So the question is whether or not you are happy to lose all that lovely NVMe speed to write everything twice, using the CPU/memory/PCIe bus with a SW R1 and have some degree of data protection, or do you keep that performance, reduce the CPU/memory/PCIe load but introduce a single-point-of-failure for losing your data by using a R0 configuration.

Ultimately that risk is for you to measure against your performance needs - which only you know, but that's the crux of the issue - R1 for slower but more reliable storage, or R0 for 'throwaway' but faster performance.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Thanks - that's absolutely my thinking! SW R0 for the data disks + system on the HW R1 - giving us speed and space for the data drive and recoverability for the system partition

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is nothing faster than RAID0

Comment: Would is be possible to add more info to this to flesh it out some? As it currently stands, it is more of a comment than a full answer.